# Strange Finished message in TLS

Tags: tls, aes

I've tried to understand the content of the `Finished` message of TLS. I'm using WireShark to capture the traffic between my browser and the internet. I noticed a "strangeness" when the chosen ciphersuite is `AES_GCM`. Being it a stream-cipher, it has no padding, so, if I got it right, the data being sent in the `Finished` message should be:

- 8 bytes Explicit Nonce
- 12 bytes verify_data
- 16 bytes authentication tag

That is, **36 bytes** in total. The "problem" is that the `Finished` message packet size is **40 bytes**.

And here it is:

## Server-to-client

[image]

**Why is the message packet 40 bytes? And what are the red bytes?**

**And why does WireShark see two `Hello Request`s?**

And another this... the Client answers with a **176 bytes** packet:

## Client-to-server

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure this is not a decoding error? Anything after `ChangeCipherSpec` is encrypted. Are you sure it's not just WireShark trying to interpret some binary garbage that it can't decrypt?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I didn't realize when I answered, but this is a dupe of [Crazy Finished Message in TLS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57807/crazy-finished-message-in-tls)

The decodings as HelloRequest are indeed as @Stackz suggests because Wireshark **can't decode encrypted** records. It tries anyway, and only if it *detects* a decode failure it suppresses the decode and displays "Encrypted Handshake Message". Here it didn't detect the decode was completely bogus.

Every handshake **message** (within a handshake record) begins with a **prefix** of 1-byte msg_type and 3-byte length, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4 . Thus you have:

* 8 bytes explicit nonce

* 16 bytes encryption of 1byte=0x14 type, 3bytes=0x00000C len, 12bytes verify_data

* 16 bytes authtag

TOTAL 40

On the client side, *maybe* the client immediately initiated another handshake; 136 bytes is plausible for ClientHello, especially if "optimized" with knowledge what the server just agreed to.