# Crazy Finished Message in TLS

Tags: aes, tls

I've tried to understand the content of the `Finished Message` of TLS. I'm using wireshark to capture the traffic between my browser and the internet. I noticed a "stangeness" when the chosen ciphersuite is AES_GCM. Beign it a stream-cipher, it has no padding, so, if I got it right, the data being sent in the Finished Message is:

- 8 bytes Explicit Nonce
- 12 bytes verify_data
- 16 bytes authentication tag

That is, **36 bytes** in total. The "problem" is that the Finished Message packet size is **40 bytes**.

And here it is:

[image]

**Why the message packet is 40 bytes and what are the red bytes?**

**And why wireshark sees two hello requests?**

And another this... the Client answers with a **176 bytes** packet:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: I believe the nonce is 12 bytes, not 8.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about TLS and not crypto; would be better for Security.SE

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this was a perfectly reasonable fit on Crypto.SE - TLS is a cryptographic protocol, and the very reason it's "interesting" is because it was built as a protocol (that people then tried to show was cryptographically secure) rather than being cryptographically secure by construction

Answer (score 4):

Each handshake message has a header, which contains its type (as a handshake message) and length. This header is *in addition* to the record header. See [section 7.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4) for a description of the header: one byte for the message type, and three bytes for the message length.

In the case of the `Finished` message, the header should be `14 00 00 0C` (in hexadecimal), with 0x14 meaning "Finished" and `00 00 0C` encoding the message contents length (12 bytes). Therefore, what is encrypted with GCM is actually 16 bytes, not 12. GCM adds the 8-byte explicit nonce (which is combined with the 4-byte implicit nonce, yielding the 12-byte nonce that [raw GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) actually needs), and the 16-byte authentication tag, for a grand total of 40 bytes, as you observe.

Of course, this record is encrypted, so you don't see its contents; in particular, Wireshark will not show the handshake message header. All it knows from the *record* header is that the record contains "some handshake data".

---

As for your second question, it is possible that the client is not content with the handshake and wants to start a new one, immediately sending a `ClientHello` just after the `Finished`. Two handshake messages can be merged into a single "handshake" record.