# Hello Request TLS Handshake Message in Session ID based Session Resumption

Tags: tls, openssl

I tried to reuse the session using session ID...

```
$openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -reconnect -no_ticket
```

But, why i got Hello Request TLS message?

[image]
Is this mean that, My session key was updated while session reuse ?

Comment: **It's not really HelloRequest**; it's Wireshark trying to decode the encrypted Finished message and misunderstanding the nonce as data. Dupe http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57804/strange-finished-message-in-tls and http://superuser.com/questions/752605/crazy-finished-message-in-tls .

Answer (score 1):

## Wireshark Bug.

I think this is bad output in WireShark.

Because [anything after "Change Cipher Spec" is encrypted](https://archive.is/hoVvU#selection-1151.26-1155.8).

I think it is a bug in Wireshark that still tries to parse the encrypted bytes as unencrypted and then outputs garbage.

Add the private key to WireShark and try again.

See:

- https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL
- https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/

Comment: Okay! Thanks @StackzOfZtuff. I thought TLS Renegotiation took place and my session key was updated. Hello Request TLS Handshake message use for Renegotiation normally and. Mostly server will send this message to the client when he want to Re-establish the session